# SQL SUM CASE STATEMENT

Tags: sql

I have:

```
SUM
(
case
when LC.[DWC] = 0 and LC.BI = 1 then 1
else LC.[DWC] END AS DC
) 
AS [DWC]
```

But I am getting an error message:

> 'SUM' is not a recognized built-in function name.

How can I fix this?

Comment: ...what table are you querying?

Comment: What's the whole SQL query?

Comment: Please show the rest of your query...  Also, what DBMS are you using?

Comment: You shouldn't have "as DC" within the sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using sql-server:

```
Select SUM(CASE WHEN (LC.[DWC] = 0 and LC.BI = 1) THEN 1 ELSE LC.[DWC] END) AS [DWC] 
FROM LC
```